# How to change app's platform from Windows 8.1 to 8?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-store

I create my game-application for Windows 8.1 and upload it to Windows Store ([link](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/pentominoes/9cf45ae4-630e-44ce-bb1d-1cb90e907816)), but it's only for 8.1. I created it in VS'13. Help me, please. How I can change platform of project in VS'13 from 8.1 to 8?

Comment: You can edit the .csproj file with a text editor and force the TargetPlatformVersion back to 8.0.  That however doesn't take care of having to fix xaml and the app manifest, possibly code.  Best to assume that just about everybody took advantage of the free 8.1 update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/visual-studio-2013-support-for-targeting-windows-8/
:

> Visual Studio 2013 will NOT support creation of new Windows 8 store
>   apps, you’ll only be able to create Windows 8.1 store apps.   However
>   you will be able to edit and build existing Windows 8 projects with
>   Visual Studio 2013.
>
> So if you want to continue to target Windows 8 when creating new store
>   apps, you are going to need both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio
>   2013 installed. You’ll really only need Visual Studio 2012 to create
>   the project, and once it’s created you can switch over to Visual
>   Studio 2013.